# Evento para cancelar reserva si no se ha pagado al llegar el día de inicio

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Cuento con un sistema de reservas cuyas operaciones se ejecutan correctamente salvo la de cancelar automáticamente reservas que no hayan sido pagadas al llegar su fecha de inicio.

Para hacerlo había pensado en implementar un evento para la base de datos MySQL, concretamente el siguiente:

```html
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT
Cancelar
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-06-20 23:59:00'
BEGIN
UPDATE reservashotel SET estado='cancelado' WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), fecha_inicio) =0 AND pago=0; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Y cual seria el problema con esto? ademas de que al ejecutarlo a las 23:59, nunca cancelarias nada?

Comment: Bien pensado. Ahora, la pregunta es?

Comment: Sí, que se me ha pasado. La cuestión es que no llega a funcionar. Tal vez el problema sea la hora como me han comentado más arriba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola espero que este bien, si quieres intenta esta forma y puedes agregar mas casos, como por ejemplo cuando falte un día tome algún estado para avisarle al cliente que esta cerca de cancelarse su reserva.

```
UPDATE reservasHotel SET estado=CASE
WHEN DATE(fecha_inicio)=DATE(CURDATE())
THEN 'cancelado'
END
WHERE pago=0;
```